# Silent command-line install of Gitahead?

Tags: gitahead

Need to install gitahead via SCCM on our lab machines. Gitahead provides .exe installers, not .msi files. Need to find correct flags/parameters for silent install.

I've already tried /qn /q /silent /verysilent and the other common ones. They all still pop up the installer GUI.

Stackoverflow seems like a weird place to get support for a non-coding problem, but I'm doing as githead requests on their site: "Ask questions about using GitAhead on Stack Overflow by including the 'gitahead' tag." -okay, that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they use [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io) (an alternative to MSI technology).  Silent installs need a /S or /SD switch and if I remember correctly it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Paul! Yes, that did the trick - silly of me to not have tried /S

Question resolved! I upvoted you but because I'm new here, it doesn't seem to have publicly shown.